# Is it fine to write something that has no relation to my local life or language or culture?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, culture

I am writing a novel (well, I have started to), with a fantasy middle ages and magic sort of background and English, Greek and meaningless names. I am from India, but my story really feels 'European'. Should I continue as it is? or make some changes?

Comment: I think this question might be better suited to [writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @celtschk Agreed, it would be **better** at writers, but it isn't really **off-topic** as such. He is asking specifically about the **world building** aspect of writing a fantasy novel. Specifically whether it is better to build settings similar to what you actually have experience with. Most of the issues caused by this involve the writing not the world building, so it would be better to move to writers, but maybe it could be reworded to limit it to the issues in just the world building part? Not sure of the value, since he'd still need to deal with those writing issues, though.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? Nobody can keep you from writing about whatever you want. Karl May wrote western stories despite never having been to America and it was a huge success.

Comment: What do you mean by "feels 'European'"?

Comment: Why are you thinking that you should make changes?  What feels unsatisfactory about what you've written so far?  I don't see anything wrong with a fantasy middle ages with magic and English, Greek, and meaningless names written by someone with a perspective from India.  Are you worried that your use of names won't look right to someone from the US or UK?  Don't feel familiar enough with the tropes?  What?  I'm not sure how much advice someone could give without reading what you have.  We'd be better at helping you with more specific questions.

Comment: I won't stop you

Comment: I think your question, as currently stated, is opinion based.  If you can add evaluation criteria for the answers, that will allow us to reopen the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you write about "a fantasy middle ages" background, you are tapping into a deep well of shared understanding. Quite a lot of it is actually wrong, but that does not matter. You don't have to *explain* that the knights are the warrior caste, or that serfs are poor and oppressed, or that many senior prelates are corrupt and self-serving. Your readers expect that.

When you are building your own world, make it close enough to this common preconception to be *recognizable*, yet add enough of your own developments to make it *distinctive*. As Mike wrote in his comment, the common middle age imagery isn't owned by people of European descent.